# Missing module "aws-exports" among other Amplify and AWS files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify

I was sent a "trial project" by a company looking to hire. It's a simple project but uses Amplify and AWS. The CTO told me I need to have a certain version of Node (10.18.1 or 10.19.0) and that I should run yarn install and everything will be good to go. So I completely uninstalled Node, installed NVM and the version of node I'm supposed to use. Then I opened the project and ran yarn install.

When I open the project in browser I am apparently a module, ./aws-exports, among other files that seem to be related to Amplify and AWS. I've noticed that most of these files are in the gitignore. But again, the CTO told me that I shouldn't have to do any setup.

I've tried installing with Npm instead. Using different versions of node. All sorts of silly little fixes and I'm just totally lost.

[image: Compile Error]

[image: Compile Error]

[image: When using NPM rather than Yarn]

[image: Versions of Node the CTO told me to use]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sharing what you have tried (actual commands and outputs) will be helpful.

Comment: Just added some screen shots!

Answer (score 2):

The file ./aws-exports will be created after the initialisation of Amplify
(https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart?sdk=js#the-init-process)

It is in .gitignore because it contains configurations information of the AWS account, which you have configured in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Does the project have a README? If so, read that. If not, don't work there.

Google the missing package name. If you find nothing, it is likely a private package.

A quick Google search gets me this: https://bit.dev/bondz/react-epic-spinners/orbit-spinner

And this: https://docs.bit.dev/docs/installing-components#configuring-bit-registry

Use Google.